# Supabase update user phone number after authentication

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

Hi I am trying to update user phone number after authentication.

1. I build an app using supabase and next js
2. User authenticate using google login
3. then I want user to confirm their mobile number so i present them a box to provide mobile numner

to do so I am using this function with supabase-js v2

```
const {data: { session },} = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
        phone: `${mobile}`,  
    });
```

it sends user the OTP but I can see in the auth users table the phone number is not updated. Also when I verify the users mobile number with OTP it does not work.

ps: using message bird for OTP message.

Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on the client-side, the flow is

1. Call `const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({phone: 'xxxx'})` https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-updateuser
2. Call `const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.verifyOtp({ phone, token, type: 'sms'})` to complete the update.

If you're doing this in a secure server-side environment you can use the admin method:

```js
const { data: user, error } = await supabase.auth.admin.updateUserById(
  '6aa5d0d4-2a9f-4483-b6c8-0cf4c6c98ac4',
  { phone: xxxxx }
)
```